# Remove Border/Outline from IconButton in Extendscript Toolkit

Tags: javascript, button, border, extendscript, outline

Working on a plugin for Adobe After Effects, learning as I go!

I've got everything working, except im looking to remove the default grey border/outline that is added to my iconbutton.

Looking for something like this:

```
var mybuttomImage = new File(["image.png"]);
var myButton = window.add("iconbutton",undefined,mybuttonImage);
myButton.size = [30,30];

myButton.outline = 0;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

After a bit of searching I found that adding this line to the end removed the border/outline.

```
{style: "toolbutton"}
```

So in practice it would be:

```
var mybuttomImage = new File(["image.png"]);
var myButton = window.add("iconbutton",undefined,mybuttonImage,{style: "toolbutton"});
myButton.size = [30,30];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Adobe After Effects so kind of a longshoot but what about replacing `myButton.outline = 0;` with `myButton.style.outline = "";`

Comment: Unfortunately not, thanks for the effort! I'm not sure .style is a thing in extendscript toolkit?

Comment: Oh alright my bad then :). Just posted in case it was a simple typo